# probelm with zsh: command not found

Tags: apache

I'm new to this area and I'm studying the PHP language.
i am trying to access this file

`config apache /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

but the terminal gives me this message

`zsh: command not found: config`

how could I solve?

Comment: Nothing in the question has anything to do with PHP. Why do you think `config` should be a command you can run?

Comment: Where did you get this line from? What OS are you using? In most scenarios vi /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf would open the config file for editing

Answer (score -1):

This a text file that you can edit with any text editor

try:

vi /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf